# Check box info retrieve

Tags: android, checkbox

Hey i am adding check boxes through sqlite , i have to get info about perticular checkbox how i get the information or id ?

here is the code its sample

```
 checkboxLayout21 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Textview_layout21);
    for (int j=0; j < 12; j++ ){
        CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        cb1.setText(chkstring1[j]);
        cb1.setId(j);

        cb1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        checkboxLayout21.addView(cb1);
```

Comment: you must set click listener or setOnCheckedChangeListener for those and in onClick() method get your info

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe your problem a bit more specified.

If you want to save ids and info to your checkboxes you can write your own class that extends Checkbox and add that info there.

If you want to be able to get your checkboxes in a later stage you should save them in an array Checkbox[].